# How do I submit a browser plugin to software center

Tags: software-center, firefox, application-development, plugins

We have an app divided in two parts, a browser plugin and the actual app. The `plugin` is used to start our desktop app. These are not open-source.

We want to submit our app to the software center but int the guidelines says that all should be installable in `/opt/`

If i can not put my plugin in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/` what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, however, put your package in /opt and then create symlinks to needed files within directories where they will be found.

Comment: Do you mean to create the links in a script after installation? sorry by the delay!!

Comment: Yes, installation can run post-deployment scripts. You could do that there.